# can't figure out using loops inside an array

Tags: java, processing

In my homework there's an term that between 2 nodes ,nodes from previous clicks should stay on the screen and there should be lines that join each node with the next one (and the last is joined to the first node). There should be no other lines besides these lines (and the grid lines of course).I've tried to doing that by using loop inside array. But its not the answer im looking for....

```java
int [] a;
int [] b;
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

class Point {
    int x, y, r;

    Point(int x, int y, int r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    void Draw() {
        circle(this.x, this.y, this.r*2);
    }
}

int n_part=10;
void setup(){
    size(600,360);

    a = new int [100];
    b = new int [100];
}

void draw () {

    background (255);

    int gridW = width/n_part;
    int gridH = height/n_part;

    stroke(210);
    noFill();
    for (int row = 0; row < n_part; row++){ 
        int gridY = 0 + row*gridH;
        for (int col = 0; col < n_part; col++) {
            int gridX = 0+ col* gridW;
            rect (gridX, gridY, gridW, gridH);   
        }
    }

    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    fill(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++ i) {
        Point p = points.get(i);
        p.Draw();
    }
}

void mousePressed() {
    int gridW = width/n_part;
    int gridH = height/n_part;

    int x = round(mouseX / (float)gridW) * gridW;
    int y = round(mouseY / (float)gridH) * gridH;

    points.add(new Point(x, y, 5));
    {
    for (int j=0; j < a.length; j++) 
        a [j] = (mouseX / (int)gridW) * gridW;
    for (int k=0; k < b.length; k++) 
        b [k] = height;
    }
}

void mouseReleased(){
    for (int k=0; k < a.length; k++) 
        line (0, 0, a [k], b [k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you've to do is to draw  lines between consecutive points.

The next index of a point `i` is `i+1`. For the last point it is 0. This can be achieved by the modulo (`%`) operator (h`(i+1) % points.size()`).

Get the 2 consecutive points in a loop and draw a line between them:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++ i) {
    Point p1 = points.get(i);
    Point p2 = points.get((i+1) % points.size());
    line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);   
}
```

See the example:

[image]

```java
void draw () {

    background (255);

    int gridW = width/n_part;
    int gridH = height/n_part;

    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(210);
    noFill();
    for (int row = 0; row < n_part; row++){ 
        int gridY = 0 + row*gridH;
        for (int col = 0; col < n_part; col++) {
            int gridX = 0+ col* gridW;
            rect (gridX, gridY, gridW, gridH);   
        }
    }

    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    fill(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++ i) {
        Point p = points.get(i);
        p.Draw();
    }

    strokeWeight(3);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++ i) {
        Point p1 = points.get(i);
        Point p2 = points.get((i+1) % points.size());
        line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);   
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother...do you have resources other than the coding trains video on processing?
In google there's almost nothing processing...

Comment: yes..btw im facing a lot problem with functions like im trying my best but not understanding the concept..

Comment: @NoMansLand [Processing](https://processing.org/) is based on java. It uses Java syntax. Java doesn't have functions, it just has classes and methods. That's the reason why you can't find anything. See [Processing - Functions](https://processing.org/examples/functions.html).